# Problem with tensorflow function when function is called within itself

Tags: python, tensorflow

It seems tensorflow cannot build @tf.function when the function is called within itself. Consider below for a simple calculation of factorial of a number:

```
import tensorflow as tf
#@tf.function
def f(n):
    out = tf.cond(tf.equal(n,0), lambda: 1, lambda: tf.multiply(n, f(n-1)))
    return out
f(5)
```

When @tf.function is commented, it works fine but with @tf.function it runs forever. Any ideas how to fix this condition?

Comment: I think It's not supported. Feel free to open a ticket on Github.